# Extreme Value Theorem proof help

Tags: analysis, alternative-proof

**Extreme Value Theorem**: *If $f$ is a continuous function on an interval [a,b],

then $f$ attains its maximum and minimum values on [a,b].*

**Proof from my book**:  Since $f$ is continuous, then $f$ has the least upper   bound, call it $M$. Assume there is no value $c \in [a,b]$ for which $f(c)=M$.
Therefore, $f(x)<M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Define a new function $g$ by

$g(x)=\frac{1}{M-f(x)}$

Observe $g(x)>0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$ and that $g$ is continuous and bounded on [a,b]. Therefore there exists $K>0$ such that $g(x)\le K$ for every $x\in [a,b]$. Since for each $x \in [a,b]$,

$g(x)= \frac{1}{M-f(x)} \le K$ is equivalent to $f(x)\le M-\frac{1}{K}$,

we have contradicted the fact that $M$ was assumed to be the least upper bound of $f$ on [a,b].
Hence, there must be a balue $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=M$.

**Q**: Where does the function $g$ come from? Is there a popular alternative proof?

Comment: using Bolzano-weierstrass ,there is an alternate nicer proof.see :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: @StefanSmith, $f$ is bounded by the boundedness theorem

Comment: @Elimination : Thanks, you're right.  I had to Google "the boundedness theorem".  The proof should mention why $f$ must be bounded, unless it is clear from context, from something immediately before it in the OP's book.  I still prefer the proof that Halil Duru cites.

Comment: How come we assumed that $g(x) \le K$, when what we need to prove in the first place is that a continuous function like this will be less that equal to its least upper bound, and not just strictly less than that. That's where the proof began right? With assuming $f(x) \lt M$.

Answer (score 14):

The "simplest" proof I know goes something like this : If $M$ is the supremum of $f$, then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$. Now, $(x_n)$ itself may not be convergent, but since $[a,b]$ is compact, it will have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Suppose $x_{n_k} \to c \in [a,b]$, then $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(c)$. But $f(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $f(x_n)$, and hence must converge to $M$. Hence, $f(c) = M$.

Answer (score 10):

This is quite a simple proof, isn't it? Why do you want a 'popular alternative proof'?

The proof can't be *too* simple, because the result is not true if $f$ is defined over $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb R$. For instance, define $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ by $f(x) = x^3 - x$. Then $f$ doesn't attain its maximum in $[-1,0]$, because $-\sqrt\frac{1}{3} \notin \mathbb Q$. Hence any proof of your theorem must use the properties of the real numbers in an essential way.

As an illuminating exercise, try to see where the proof breaks down if $f$ is only defined over the rational numbers.

Comment: May you guide where the proof breaks Sir ? @TonyK

Comment: @Orion_Pax The least upper bound property fails to hold, so M isn't actually in the domain of f

Answer (score 5):

> Where does the function $g$ come from?

We need to show that $f(x)=M$ for some $x$. A natural move is to consider the difference between $f$ and $M$. Let $d(x)=M-f(x)$. $f(x)=M \leftrightarrow d(x)=0$. The reason that the definition $g(x)=(d(x))^{-1}$ uses the inverse of the difference is that if $g$ is bounded from **above** by $K>0$, than $d$ is bounded from **below** by $K^{-1}>0$. $g$ is bounded by the boundedness theorem, thus we know a **positive** lower bound of $d$. Applying the boundedness theorem directly to $d$ is useless because the lower bound of $d$ can be $0$. This is the intuition behind $g$.

Comment: Sir the proof shows the maximum bound which is being achived that is f(x) = M for some c . But what about the minimum value which the function is taking how to show it takes the minimum value too ? ( I am referring to a situation where maxium of function is at y= 5 but minimum is at y= -3 ) that is not symmetric about y axis

Comment: @Orion_Pax If I understood you correctly, you want the proof for the minimum value. It's similar to the proof for the maximum value, but is mirrored with respect to the Y axis. You start with proving that $f$ has the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Actually i already told whats wrong with that mirror part , may you once check this :  @beroal

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4431692/922054 this @beroal

Comment: @Orion_Pax Okay, I wrote the mirror proof in full https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4445009/7011 . Comment there if your think there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a "popular alternative proof". This is an alternative proof. I don't know how popular it is, but I like it. It uses the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (convergent subsequences) but hardly anything else, no least upper bounds; it skips the step of proving boundedness, going straight for the maximum. It could be shortened by using the fact that the set of rational numbers is countable, but that seems unnecessarily sophisticated.

Given a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $[a,b]$, we will show that
the set $Y = f([a,b])$ has a greatest element.

For each positive integer $n$, define a finite set $Q_n = \{\frac{p}{q}: p,q \text{ integers, } 0 < q \le n, |p| \le n\}$.

Choose $y_n\in Y$ so as to maximize the number of elements in the set $\{r\in Q_n: y_n > r\}$, and choose $x_n\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_n) = y_n$.

The sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence converging to a point $c\in[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, the corresponding subsequence of $\{y_n\}$ converges to $f(c)$. We will show that $f(c)$ is the greatest element of $Y$.

Assume for a contradiction that $f(c)<y\in Y$. Choose a rational
number $r$ so that $f(c)<r<y$. Because of the way $y_n$ was chosen, we
have $y_n > r$ whenever $r\in Q_n$. Since $r\in Q_n$ for all
sufficiently large $n$, we have $y_n > r > f(c)$ for all sufficiently
large $n$. But this is absurd, since $\{y_n\}$ has a subsequence converging
to $f(c)$.