# Are continuous functions with compact support bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

While studying measure theory I came across the following fact: $\mathcal{K}(X) \subset C_b(X)$ (meaning the continuous functions with compact support are a subset of the bounded continuous functions). This seems somehow odd to me; I've tried to prove it but did not succeed. Could someone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $f \in \mathcal{K}(X)$, and $S$ the support of $f$. What do you know about $f(S)$? And what about $f(X\setminus S)$?

Comment: Your question is in fact Weierstrass's theorem. Have you studied it or not? This is in order for the answerers to know at what level to "calibrate" their arguments.

Comment: In any topology, the image of a compact set is compact (under a continuous map).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have
$$f(X)\subseteq\{0\}\cup f(\mathrm{supp}(f)),$$
which is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ (since $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is compact and $f$ is continuous), hence bounded.

Comment: And why is that compact? It seems to me that your proof is circular, assuming exactly what the OP wants to prove.

Comment: @AlexM. Because the image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact and the union of two compact sets is compact.

Comment: Assuming that the OP knows that the image of a compact through a continuous function is again compact, then yes. But since the OP doesn't even know Weierstrass's theorem (which is simpler), I suspect that he asks for a much more basic proof, one close to first principles.

Comment: Technically, isn't it true that $f(X) = \{0\} \cup f(\text{supp}(f))$? Then we can see that it is compact directly by compactness of $\{0\}$ and $f(\text{supp}(f))$ (and the fact that the finite union of compact sets is compact).

Comment: I take my above comment back, since $\{x\in X: f(x) =0\}$ need not be non-empty. Nevertheless, if $\{x\in X: f(x) =0\}\ne \emptyset$, then $f(X) = \{0\} \cup f(\text{supp}(f))$. On the other hand, if $\{x\in X: f(x) =0\}= \emptyset$, then $f(X) = f(\text{supp}(f))$. In either case, $f(X)$ is compact.

Comment: And membership in $L^p$ follows from this because $supp(f)$ and $range(f)$ are both bounded, correct?

Answer (score 4):

If you do know the Weierstraß theorem, then you can prove it like that:

Let $f \in \mathcal{K}(X)$ and denote by $K$ the support of $f$. Then $f|_{K^c}=0$ by the very definition of the support. Moreover, by the Weierstraß theorem,  $f|_K$ is bounded. Combining both facts, proves that $f$ is bounded.

If you do *not* know the Weierstraß theorem, then have e.g. a look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/464930/) (note that the proof does not only work for a compact interval $[a,b]$, but for any compact set $K$).

Comment: This is a circular "proof", because the OP wants precisely the proof of Weierstrass's theorem. Otherwise what meaning would the question have?

Comment: @AlexM. Well, I think that the OP is simply not aware of the fact that Weierstraß theorem can be applied. (Did you downvote both answers?)

Comment: Yes, the downvotes are mine. See the OP's comment under Spenser's answer.

Comment: @saz $-1+1=0$ ;-)

Comment: @AlexM. I see, but it's hardly our fault. If the OP doesn't given any details what he has tried or what kind of (mathematical) background he has, then it's pretty hard to answer the question properly, right?

Comment: @Spenser Yeah, I agree. :)