# $f(X)\subset \{0\}\cup f(\text{supp}(f))$ vs $f(X)\subset f(\text{supp}(f))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f$ has [compact support](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactSupport.html) and is continuous (say we are in the simplest case of $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$).

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344706/are-continuous-functions-with-compact-support-bounded), and can't understand why there needs to be a $\{0\}$ in the expression $$f(X)\subset\{0\}\cup f(\text{supp}(f))$$
Even if $\{x\ : f(x)=0\}\ne\emptyset$, won't we have that $0\in f(\text{supp}(f))?$

tryin to think of counterexamples with a function such that $\{x\ :\ f(x)\ne 0\}=(a,b)\cup(b,c)$ for some $a<b<c$, we get that $\text{supp}(f)=\overline{(a,b)\cup(b,c)}=[a,c]$, therefore $b\in \text{supp}(f)$ and $0=f(b)\in f(\text{supp}(f))$, so there would be no need for the $\{0\}$.

So either there is a counterexample, in which case I'd like to know it, or the $\{0\}$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: the continuity assumption implies that the $0$ is not necessary. A compact subset of $\Bbb{R}$ has a (finite) maximum, so we can let $M = \max \operatorname{supp}(f)$. Note that $x > M \implies f(x) = 0$. Then, by continuity,
$$f(M) = \lim_{x \to M^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to M^+} 0 = 0.$$
Thus, $0 \in f(\operatorname{supp} f)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider a function $f: X \to \Bbb R$ with $X \subseteq \Bbb R$ (like in the question you've linked) the $\{0\}$ is indeed necessary.

E.g. take $X: [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ and $f = 1_{[0,1]}$ the indicator function of $[0,1]$. Then $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $$f(X) = \{0,1\} = \{0\} \cup f(\text{supp}(X))$$ but $$f(\text{supp}(X)) = f([0,1]) = \{1\}$$