# Showing that the minimum value the continuous function will take too from the extreme value theorem in case M>|m|

Tags: calculus

From "Extreme value theorem" we say that both maximum and minimum is acheived by the continuous function in its closed interval domain , the proof goes by showing function is bounded and then proved that it needs to be achieved by showing contradiction of letting it not be the case , lets say that upper bound is M so from that proof we can surely say M is acheived , but suppose the maximum and minimum values are not symmetric about y axis , in that case only one is guaranteed to ve achieved from that proof isnt ? What about the other extreme value ? Like for example take this : M (maxima here will be acheived from Boundness theorem) , what about m (M>|m|) (minima how will we show that it will also be achieved ?) Proof which i am referring to [Extreme Value Theorem proof help](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376589/922054) [image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  The positions of the max and min have no general relation to x= 0.

Comment: x= 0 ? I didnt say anything related to that

Answer (score 1):

(This is a mirror of [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376589/7011).)

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, the range of $f$ has a lower bound by the boundedness theorem and the greatest lower bound (call it $m$) by the completeness of real numbers.

Assume that $f(x)>m$ for all $x\in [a, b]$. Then function $g$ defined on $[a, b]$ by $$g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)-m}$$ is continuous and positive. Hence there is a positive $K$ such that $g(x)\leq K$ for all $x\in [a, b]$ by the boundedness theorem.

Therefore, $f(x)\geq m+\frac{1}{K}$ for all $x\in [a, b]$. But then $m+\frac{1}{2K}$ which is greater than $m$ is a lower bound of the range of $f$, contradiction the fact that $m$ is the greatest lower bound of the range of $f$. Therefore, there is a $c\in [a, b]$ such that $f(c)=m$.